# Bug when i try to print « with cout

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm having problem when i want to print Guillemet («) with cout, the print result in console is ½. I wonder if there are ways to make the print result become "«".

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "«" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I use Code::Blocks 16.01 (MinGW) on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: As a side note: the standard output on Linux [supports](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6109eb09af8a910c) that character.